# how to avoid permission denied with a subcollection in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a denied permission when i tried to read my subcollection .

This is my collection and subcollection i have Teams/membersList

[image]

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  //Grants only a user access to its own data 
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    //Allow requests from authenticated users
    match/Users/{document=**}{
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match/Teams/{document=**}{
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    match /membersList/{membersList} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
  }
   match /Teams/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  match /Teams/memberLists/{document=**}{
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
}

}
```

this is the part of my code with a denied permission

```
 let fetch = async () => {
    firestore()
      .collection("Teams")
      .where("uid", "==", await AsyncStorage.getItem("userID"))
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          console.log("no documents found");
        } else {
          querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
            let Teams = doc._data.Activity;
            console.log(Teams);
            updateActivity((arr) => [...arr, Teams]);
            console.log(Activity);

            firestore()
              .collection("membersList")
              .get()
              .then((documentSnapshot) => {
                console.log("User exists: ", documentSnapshot.exists);

                if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                  console.log("User data: ", documentSnapshot.data());
                }
              });
          });
        }
      });
```

I've still have permission denied after writing this rules. Do you have any ideas ??

Comment: Rules on their own do nothing. Please edit your question to also include the minimum code that is needed to get the error message. And given your `request.auth != null` checks, show in that code that this condition is met (for example, bu logging the UID right before accessing the database).

Comment: @frankvanPuffelen , i add my code, the permission failed when i tried to go inside the subcollection membersList

Comment: How can we be certain that `await AsyncStorage.getItem("userID")` is an actual UID of a signed in user? Can you reproduce it if you use `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` instead?

Comment: it's the UID because i used everywhere, for my first collections Users and Teams, everything was working fine until i created the subcollection on a Team collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
firestore()
  .collection("membersList")
  .get()
```

This reads from a top-level collection called `membersList`, which doesn't exist in your rules. So the user doesn't have access to the data, and the read gets rejected. Even if the collection doesn't exist, the read gets rejected.

If you want to read from the `membersList` subcollection of the current team, that's be:

```
doc
  .ref
  .collection("membersList")
  .get()
```

Comment: thansk it's working now it doesn' fine the data on the collection but i have no problem with permission anymore !